# Linking to the view folder in MVC - jQuery load function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using Code Igniter. I am using jquery's load function. I have added that function to the onclick event of a button. When I click on it I fill a div named sample with the contents of another page called sample.php. This sample.php file in located in the view folder of CI. When I use the following code it searches for the sample.php file in the root folder and not in the views folder.

```
$('#sample').load('sample.php');
```

And when I type in the right path it says Access is Forbidden. I need to link to this sample.php file in the view folder. I'm sure there is a way around. I need help !

Comment: you could have created required function in controller and loaded appropriate view, and use that controller url in jquery .load()...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller write a function like

```
function sample_fun
{
   $this->load->view("sample");
}
```

and in your jquery function

```
$('#sample').load('<?php echo base_url()?>sample_comtroller/sample_fun');
```